# Need help in locking selected range of cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need help in locking specific range of cells based on the selection of value from list from another cell.

To be specific, I have created data validation list for columns N5 to N36, upon selection of value "Exist" from the cell N5, I want to lock that specific row O5 to U5.

i.e "Exist" in N6 would lock O6 to U6 and so on.

Similarly for the other rows till N36.

And if the user selects "Does not Exist", then I would want those cells to remain unlocked and editable similar to the above condition.

I have tried macros from various forums using my very basic knowledge of using macros, but most of those lock the entire sheet.

Code I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N5:N36")) Is Nothing Then 
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect 

        If Target.Value = "Exist" Then 
            Range("O" & Target.Column & ":U" & Target.Column).Select Selection.Locked = False   
        Else 
            Range("O" & Target.Column & ":U" & Target.Column).Select Selection.Locked = True 
        End If 
    End If 

    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True 
End Sub
```

I would really appreciate your quick help.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you should unlock all cells that are not in that range and then protect the sheet, I'll look into that code a little bit ;)

Comment: Hi @GoosvandenBekerom, 
Below is one of the codes which I used actually, where after my selection from one cell, entire sheet is getting locked.

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N5:N36")) Is Nothing Then
         
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect
         
        If Target.Value = "Exist" Then
            Range("O" & Target.Column & ":U" & Target.Column).Select
            Selection.Locked = False
        Else
            Range("O" & Target.Column & ":U" & Target.Column).Select
            Selection.Locked = True
        End If
    End If
     
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
     
End Sub

Comment: dont add that code in the comments, add it in your question. I posted an answer below, you could check that out

Comment: i added the code to your question that you put in the comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying (**Tried And Tested**)? Also see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/ms-excel-crashes-when-vba-code-runs/13861640#13861640). It's worth a read.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim sPass As String

    '~~> Password
    sPass = "BlahBLah"

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '~~> For excel 2003 use .Count instead of .CountLarge
    '~~> In case of multiple cells were changed        
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N5:N36")) Is Nothing Then
        If UCase(Trim(Target.Value)) = "EXIST" Then
            rw = Target.Row

            With ActiveSheet
                .Unprotect sPass

                .Cells.Locked = False

                .Range("O" & rw & ":U" & rw).Locked = True

                .Protect Password:= sPass , DrawingObjects:=True, _
                Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
            End With
        End If
    End If

Letscontinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Letscontinue
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for helping Siddharth. But when I am the running the code, I am facing an error as "Compile error Expected Sub, Function or property". Please suggest how to proceed further. Thanks again.

Comment: Ah Ok. I got it... See the updated post. You may have to refresh the page to see it

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot Siddharth for your help. Could you please let me know the change you have made, it would help me understand. Thanks once again.

Comment: See the edit history. :) I had forgotten to put "=" in `Password:= sPass`

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this:

```
Sub LockCells()

    'unprotect the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect

    'unlock all cells
    Cells.Locked = False
    Cells.FormulaHidden = False

    Dim cell As Range

    'find all cells that need to be locked
    For Each cell In Range("N5:N36")
        If cell = "Exist" Then

            Range("O" & cell.Row & ":U" & cell.Row).Locked = True
            Range("O" & cell.Row & ":U" & cell.Row).FormulaHidden = True

        End If
    Next cell

    'protect the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Will try this and get back to you. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I would want to modify my question a little. If I select "Exist" in N5, then I would want to lock only that row i.e. O5 to U5. Similarly for all individual rows from N5 to N36. Please suggest the appropriate answer. Apologies for the change.

Comment: make changes to your question don't put them in comments like i said before, change your question above or I can't help you

Comment: Apologies for adding it in the comment. I have edited my question accordingly. Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: What you want is possible, and with the info i gave you you could do it yourself, it would make a very slow code tho if you want to achieve that. I will change my answer a little bit and you would be able to figure out the rest

Comment: I changed the answer, actually this should do what you want ;) it will lock al the rows that have "Exist" in column n and the other rows will stay editable